# read csv files pandas slice arrays

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm a python newbie and am having trouble reading a csv to pandas and working with it. Here is a bit of my csv file:

```
A   B
1   56
2   76
3   23
4   45
5   54
6   65
7   22
```

And my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from math import exp
from math import sqrt

g = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv')

a = g.iloc[2:4,1]
print(a)
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I've also tried:

```
a = g.iloc[2:4,'B']
```

and many other permutations for defining columns and rows.

Also when I print g, I get the following:

```
             B
A             
2015-05-01  56
2015-05-02  76
2015-05-03  23
2015-05-04  45
2015-05-05  54
2015-05-06  65
2015-05-07  22
```

I can't understand why A and B are not aligned.

I'm just using this an example, but in general I'd like to read in large csv files and then perform operations on certain aspects of the matrix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly  [`DataFrame.from_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv) whilst still supported, it's better to use the top level [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) instead as this supports more functionality.

So this:

```
a = g.iloc[2:4,1]
```

is wrong syntax, you want:

```
a = g.iloc[2:4]['A']
```

Secondly, by default `DataFrame.from_csv` uses the first column as the index which is why column 'A' is your index, if you passed `index_col=None` then you get the desired result:

```
In [6]:
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path)

Out[6]:
    B
A    
1  56
2  76
3  23
4  45
5  54
6  65
7  22
In [7]:    
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path, index_col=None)

Out[7]:
   A   B
0  1  56
1  2  76
2  3  23
3  4  45
4  5  54
5  6  65
6  7  22
```

Correct syntax:

```
In [9]:   
df.iloc[2:4]['A']

Out[9]:
2    3
3    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Additionally [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) the default for `index_col` is `None` so your problem with the alignment would not have happened if you had used `read_csv`.

Please check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) on indexing and selecting.

**EDIT**

As @Jeff suggested and I always agree with Jeff, for this kind of selection `ix` is the typical selection method but it's behaviour differs from `iloc` in that it does include the end row selection unlike `iloc`:

```
In [10]:    
df.ix[2:4,'A']

Out[10]:
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

So I don't know what you wanted row selection-wise but be aware of the different semantics.

**Update**

Note that [`.ix`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) will be deprecated in the future, you can achieve the same result using `.loc`:

```
In [202]:
df.loc[2:4,'A']

Out[202]:
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is a use case for ix

Comment: @Jeff I agree but I wasn't sure what the OP's desired behaviour was for the row selection as `.ix` row selection will include the end index row which is different to `iloc`